# Midpointrounding

Tags: c#

I'm trying to round off the following values, but I don't know what's wrong.

```
NewValue -=(System.Math.Round(Global.WorkData.ValueOld - System.Math.Round (Global.WorkData.ValueOld * 20, 0) / 20, 2 ));
```

And this is what I did:

```
NewValue -=(System.Math.Round(Global.WorkData.ValueOld, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero - System.Math.Round(Global.WorkData.ValueOld * 20, 2,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) / 20, 2 ));
```

Could you please tell me what's wrong in my code? why I can't compile it? 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got at least one bracketing error, so it's trying to subtract a decimal value from a `MidpointRounding`.

However, I still can't work out what you're really trying to do.

I *strongly* recommend that you split this statement up - split the calls to `Round`, and then one using the values. For example:

```
decimal oldValue = Global.WorkData.ValueOld; // For convenience
decimal roundTo2 = Math.Round(oldValue, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
decimal roundTo20 = Math.Round(oldValue * 20, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
newValue -= roundTo2 - (roundTo20/20);
```

I still can't work out exactly what you want to do with the results - what's the 2 at the end of the statement meant to be for? What is the first statement in your question meant to be? Maybe you want:

```
decimal oldValue = Global.WorkData.ValueOld; // For convenience
decimal roundedBy20ths = Math.Round(oldValue * 20, 2,
                                    MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) / 20;
decimal remainder = Math.Round(oldValue - roundedBy20ths, 2,
                               MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
newValue -= remainder;
```

? That might be it, but I really don't know...

Shorter statements make the code clearer and let you find this kind of error *much* more easily.

Comment: Thanks Jon,I'll try this suggestion. I think it shorter statements should be practice in writing code so that it would be clearer. This is a code of somebody and we're trying to renew the code he made. It's quite tedious:-(

Answer (score 5):

You have missed out a bracket:

```
NewValue -=(System.Math.Round(Global.WorkData.ValueOld, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero - System.Math.Round(Global.WorkData.ValueOld * 20, 2,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) / 20, 2 ));


NewValue -=(System.Math.Round(Global.WorkData.ValueOld, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero**)** - System.Math.Round(Global.WorkData.ValueOld * 20, 2,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) / 20, 2 );
```

Hope this helps you out.

I think you're aiming for the following: (but i'm not 100%)

```
decimal OldValue = Global.WorkData.ValueOld;
decimal OldValueMaths = (OldValue - (OldValue * 20)) / 20;

NewValue -= Math.Round(OldValueMaths, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Comment: Hi Lloyd, thanks for this code, but these seems to be not working:-(